# setting basic react JS material UI template

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

*I’m trying to set up my first react is website with docker and react js material UI package.*

All I want is running a process that serves the following source code but the GitHub doesn’t have any instructions.

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/pages/premium-themes/onepirate

help requires to figure out how to build docker image for this and how can I set up my docker workflow to deploy this with docker daemon?

Do I just npm install and npm run?

Any help would be much appreciated!